# Jenkinsfile how to mimic 2 separate test and build jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the old configuration we had 2 jobs, test and build.

The build ran after test had run successfully, but we could manually trigger build if we want to skip the tests.

After we switched to multiple pipeline using Jenkinsfile, we had to put those 2 build jobs in to the same file:

```
stage('Running tests'){
   ...
}

stage('Build'){
   ...
}
```

So now the build step is only triggered after running tests successfully, and we cannot manually trigger build, without commenting out the test steps and commit to the repository.

I am wondering if there is a better approach/practise to utilise the Jenkinsfile to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pipeline and Jenkinsfile is becoming the standard and preferred way of running jobs on Jenkins now a days. So using a Jenkinsfile is certainly the way to go.

One way to solve the problem is to make the job parameterized:

```
// Set the parameter properties, this will be done at the first run so that we can trigger with parameters manually
properties([parameters([booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: 'Testing will be done if this is checked', name: 'DO_TEST')])])

stage('Running tests'){
  // Putting the check inside of the stage step so that we don't confuse the stage view
  if (params['DO_TEST']) {
    ...
  }
}

stage('Build'){
   ...
}
```

The first time the job runs, it will add a parameter to the job. After that we can trigger manually and select whether tests should run. The default value will be used when it's triggered by SCM.

Comment: Use `params.DO_TEST` to access the parameter value.

Comment: a bit off topic, do you know how to add project global environment so I can control which branch to deploy?

Comment: @StephenKing You are correct, thank you, I've updated the example.

Comment: @JamesLin I don't quite follow, maybe a separate question?

Comment: @JonS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122359/jenkins-multi-branch-how-to-set-project-global-environment-variable